# Fire-and-forget in PHP

Tags: php, stream, fire-and-forget

**Final update**

Seems like I did make a very simple error. Since I already have a stream implementation I can just not start reading from the stream :D

---

I'm trying to achieve **fire-and-forget** like functionality in PHP.

> [From php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#93441)

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
header("Content-Length: 4");
header("Connection: Close");
echo "abcd";
flush();

sleep(5);    
echo "Text user should not see"; // because it should have terminated
?>
```

This works if I open the script with a browser. (shows "abcd").
But if I open it with `file_get_contents` or some *stream* library it will wait for ~5 seconds and show the second text as well.

I'm using PHP 5.2.11 / Apache 2.0

---

**Update**

I seems there is some confusion about what I'm trying to accomplish.

I don't want to hide output using output buffers (that's stupid). I want to have the client terminate before the server starts a possibly lengthy process (`sleep(5)`) and I don't want the client to wait for it (this is what fire-and-forget means, sort off).
The use of output buffers is merely a side effect. I've amended the sample code without the use of output buffers.

What I don't understand is: why does this script behave differently when accessing it from the browser vs. fetching it in PHP with `file_get_contents("http://dev/test.php")` or some *stream* library? What I've seen in testing is that for instance `stream_get_contents` will actually block for 5 seconds before it returns any output at all, the is quite the opposite of what I want.

**Update2**

Some more results:

- The browser somehow responds to the `flush()`. I can't figure out how to replicate this behavior with *streams* in PHP, my streams keep blocking.
- I've tried `fread` and found that it behaves similar to `stream_get_contents`.
- Specifying a `maxlength` has no effect, it will still block for ~5 seconds.
- Changing the blocking mode has no effect (other than generating a bunch more calls `to stream_get_contents()`). It will wait ~5 seconds before returning anything.
- `stream_set_read_buffer` has no effect (tested on a PHP 5.3.5 sever)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you don't want to send the last text to the client, why are you outputting it to the client?

Comment: I believe you shouldn't use `ob_end_clean()` and `ob_end_flush`. Choose one.

Comment: @hakre the printing of text is an example. What I really want to do is start some process and I don't want to client to wait for it. I thought "fire and forget" would be a known term.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, I've amended the sample code to use no output buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I did make a very simple error. Since I already have a stream implementation I can just not start reading from the stream :D

Answer (score 0):

The second portion of text is showing up because you're stopping output buffering with `ob_end_flush()` and `ob_end_clean()`. When that happens PHP outputs content as normal. Try something like the following:

```
<?php

ob_start(); // turn on output buffering
print "Text the user will see.";
ob_flush(); // send above output to the user and keep output buffering on

print "Text the user will never see";

ob_end_clean(); // empty the buffer and turn off output buffering. your script should end here.

?>
```

It's important for `ob_end_clean()` to appear at the end of the script. It empties the buffer and does not send its contents to the user, thus keeping everything after `ob_flush()` hidden.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the problem. I don't want to hide output by using output buffering, I want the client to terminate while the server starts it's real task. The output buffer example you provided does not cause the client to terminate.

Comment: If that's the case output buffering is the wrong tool for the job. I'd think you would need to call a separate script (perhaps as a separate process) and `exit()` the current one.

Answer (score 0):

How do you access the script using file_get_contents? How do you access it with your browser? If you access the script without "http://", of course it will never get executed. Use the same URL as in the browser.

Edit:

The browser will render the page even before the connection is closed. Even if you flush, I don't think the connection is closed. You can fire up Wireshark and check. stream_get_contents and file_get_contents will block until they have all the output. Even if you flushed, they can't be sure that there isn't more content. Since the content-length header didn't seem to make {file,stream}_get_contents return earlier, you probably need to implement your own buffering, ala. fopen, read, fclose.

Comment: With http:// of course. I don't really mind 'silly' questions as they sometimes expose the problem, but this is kind of offensive.

Comment: Don't take stuff personal. I'm just trying to help. I have no idea of knowing what you know and what you don't. I edited this answer. Tell me if you considered the stuff I wrote there too.

Comment: I've updated my posts with results from `fread`. I don't actually know if the browser closes the connection, all I know is that the browser no longer waits for more content, I want that :D